# segmentation fault by " movl(%ebx), %eax"

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have written a program in assembly, after typing:

```
as -32 maximum.s -o maximum.o
ld -m elf_i386 maximum.o -o maximum
./maximum
```

It shows a segmentation fault and when I use gdb to debug，gdb says:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
max() at maximum.s:27
27       movl(%ebx), %eax
```

My code is:

```
section .date
data_items:
.long 23,35,67,89,212,45,233,63,45

.section .text

.globl _start
_start:
movl  $data_items, %eax
pushl %eax
call max
addl $4, %esp
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80

.type max, @function
max:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $4, %esp 
movl $0, %ecx
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx 
movl 8(%ebp), %edx 
movl (%ebx), %eax 
addl $36, %edx 
movl %edx, -4(%ebp)

loop_start:
movl -4(%ebp), %edx
cmpl %ebx, %edx
je loop_end
addl $4, %ebx
movl (%ebx), %edx
cmpl %eax, %edx
jle loop_start
movl %edx, %eax
jmp loop_start

loop_end:
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Why and how I fix it?

Comment: `section .date` should be `section .data`.

Comment: You may need to ensure ds is properly set to your data segment.

Comment: @PMF ds is data structure？

Comment: CS, DS, ES... the segment registers (or in the 32 bit memory model, actually segment selectors). Here, they basically point to a data structure indiciating what rights your application has on accessing memory. I would however assume, that at least CS and DS are set up properly at startup by the operating system - given that it finds the segments, so the above comment about a wrong section name could be the culpit already.

Comment: Linux does set up the segment registers properly, so you don't have to do anything with them at process startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your data section name.

`.section .date` should be `.section .data`

After correcting it,that is OK.

Answer (score 1):

To debug x86 asm code, use a debugger with an asm mode.  The [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has some links to helpful stuff, and instructions on how to use gdb for asm.  Step through your code, and look at the values in registers as they change.  gdb with `layout reg` highlights the changed registers after each instruction.

You may be treating data as an address.  I followed your code for a bit, but didn't take the time to be sure there was a problem.

Not the bug, but

```
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx 
movl 8(%ebp), %edx
```

should be

```
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx 
movl %ebx, %edx   # more efficient, and shorter
```